# Syntax error on token ")", Statement expected after this token

Tags: java, recursion, syntax-error

I have encountered a syntax error that I cannot figure out even with searching.

The problem is on line 12, I have been attempting to use recursive.

The full error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Syntax error on token ")", Statement expected after this token

    at Problem_14.main(Problem_14.java:12)
```

The code is:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Problem_14 {

    public static long sequence(long o) {
     long n = 0;
      if (o % 2 == 0) n = o/2; sequence(n); 
      if (o % 2 != 0) n = 3*o + 1; sequence(n);
      return n;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Long> chain = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        //Iterative sequence 
        //n → n/2 (n is even)
        //n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)

        for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
            chain.put(String.valueOf(i), sequence(i));
        }
    }

}
```

I've done all of the recommendations to no avail.

Comment: It's not the problem, but don't do this: `if (o % 2 == 0) n = o/2; sequence(n);`.  That second statement should be on its own line, not tacked to the end of the "then" clause of the `if`.

Comment: Try cleaning your project & recompile

Comment: There is no obvious syntax error, if we're counting the lines correctly (line 12 is the closing `}` of the first method).  I'd guess that you have some non-printing character in there, perhaps due to editing with a word processor rather than a source editor.

Comment: And note that the return value from those `sequence(n)` calls is falling on the floor.  The calls have no effect whatsoever (other than to cause infinite recursion).

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it's definitely on your end. Copy the code from this question (without the comments containing the `→` signs to be safe) into a new class and it should compile. The question should be closevoted IMO as the problem is not reproductible...

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look right regardless. Shouldn't:

```
 if (o % 2 == 0) n = o/2; sequence(n);
```

be

```
 if (o % 2 == 0) { n = o/2; sequence(n); }
```

Comment: I've tried that as well, but I figured I might as well shorten it to a one line if statement.

Comment: Or `sequence(n)` should be on its own line, if it's not intended to be a part of the "then" clause.

Comment: You can shorten it by removing the braces, but you're changing how it *actually* works

Comment: @duelingwarlord - It is exceedingly dumb to write a multi-line "then" clause on one line.  40 years of programming tell me this.

Comment: It's not proper use of recursion anyway, because there is no base case, meaning that this function will never terminate.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're not using a proper editor. Signs like `→` are not usually used in source files. Try saving your file in UTF-8 decoding, or better yet, use a proper EDI like Eclipse.

```
    //n → n/2 (n is even)
    //n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)
```

Comment: But you copied some content from Word? I've never seen Eclipse autocorrect -> to →

Comment: If I copy-paste your code I get a warning about the decoding. If I then proceed to select "Convert to UTF-8" I get no compile errors and it runs as expected (which mean it throws a StackOverflowError).

Comment: This is from a website(project Euler). The arrows were in the question. I've replaced them currently to an equal operator.

Comment: It throws a StackOverFlowError because your recursive function has no base case - so in theory it will never terminate. In reality it throws a StackOverFlowError. You should probably read up on recursive functions.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a one line if, you have to be very careful with your braces. The way you've written it, only the first statement of each if is actually being considered part of the then block. I recommend doing this instead:

```
if (o % 2 == 0)
{
    n = o/2;
    sequence(n);
}
if (o % 2 != 0)
{
    n = 3*o + 1;
    sequence(n);
}
```